# Изменение порядка отображения элементов

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css3

Когда-то давным давно нашёл способ отображения блоков вот при помощи такой штуки:

```css
.content {column-gap: 10px; -moz-column-gap: 10px; -webkit-column-gap: 10px; column-count: 2; -moz-column-count: 2; -webkit-column-count: 2; width: 40px;}
.content .block {display: inline-block; width: 100%; margin: 0 0 5px;}
/* Чисто для красоты */
.content .block span {display: block; width: 20px; height: 20px; line-height: 20px; text-align: center;}
.content .block:nth-child(odd) span {background: green; color: #fff;}
.content .block:nth-child(even) span {background: yellow;}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="block"><span>1</span></div>
  <div class="block"><span>2</span></div>
  <div class="block"><span>3</span></div>
  <div class="block"><span>4</span></div>
  <div class="block"><span>5</span></div>
  <div class="block"><span>6</span></div>
</div>
```

Ну и собстна сами видите как это рендерится

```
1  4
2  5
3  6
```

Можно ли как-то это сделать так, чтобы порядок был такой?

```
1  2
3  4
5  6
```

Без изменения HTML, а чисто CSS или JQ?

Comment: Все, начало новой эпохи ... десятилетия спрашивали как расположить столбцами, теперь спрашивают как не располагать столбцам ... `float: left`, `display: inline-block`, `display: table-cell` (ну и там что-то с флексами, я чутка устарел) ...

Comment: Ещё есть `display: flex;`. Но суть не в этом, а в вопросе. Если спрашивают, значит так надо.

Comment: ага, я тоже вспомнил про флексы) А такие вопросы в моем понимании ничто иное как "поиск фриланса", спрашивая основы основ ты как бы заявляешь "не хочу разбираться сам, сделайте вы, а я буду пользоваться", по этому надо не надо, не знаю, просто оставляю несмешной коммент и иду дальше xDD

Comment: Ну как бы не совсем так.. Я знаю об этом способе примерно так: "вот код и всё", описание не читал и даже не гуглил, а тут пришлось, и вот.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтоб мне за такие проблемы оды воспевали (сарказм):

```css
.content {
/* Чисто для решения проблемы */
 display: grid;
 grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
 grid-column-gap: 10px;
  /* конец решения проблемы */
 width: 40px;
}
.content .block {
 display: inline-block;
 width: 100%;
 margin: 0 0 5px;
}
/* Чисто для красоты */
.content .block span {
 display: block;
 width: 20px;
 height: 20px;
 line-height: 20px;
 text-align: center;
}
.content .block:nth-child(odd) span {
 background: green;
 color: #fff;
}
.content .block:nth-child(even) span {
 background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="block"><span>1</span></div>
  <div class="block"><span>2</span></div>
  <div class="block"><span>3</span></div>
  <div class="block"><span>4</span></div>
  <div class="block"><span>5</span></div>
  <div class="block"><span>6</span></div>
</div>
```